# float right on 2 span items in the h1 block

Tags: html, css

I am little curious to understand how the alignment works in CSS3 the below html code uses float right

```
 <h2><span class='title'>Sunrise: </span><span class='sunrise'>{{sunrise}}</span><span class='title right'>  Sunset: </span><span class='sunset right'>{{sunset}}</span></h2>
```

this is how css look like

```
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sunrise {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: blue;
}
.sunset {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: blue;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

It gives me output like below where Sunset label appears after Sunset Time instead should be before Sunset Time, for now I could fix in the emulator by reordering but not sure if the behavior remains consistent on all devices, is that float right works in reverse order, please explain, please also suggest a better css way of doing same.
[image: sunrise & sunset timings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, using `float` is not using the benefits of CSS3, it was there long before. Next to that, using a `h2` element for a title is okay, but in this example, it's not semantically correct to use a heading element since it's more than just a title that you are showing.

Using `display: flex;` and `margin-left: auto;` on the right element, it will always show most far to the right of the available space (see below example). You could also use `justify-content: space-between;` to do this. Please read more about it [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

The `datetime` attribute I added to make the time machine-readable.

```css
.heading {
  display: flex;
}

.sunset {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <div class="sunrise">
    <time datetime="17:01">17.01</time>
  </div>
  <div class="sunset">
    <time datetime="17:11">17.11</time>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: While tested in mobile device the right side text  displays only few chars

Comment: @Naga Unfortunately, I don't know how you've set this up. Please ask a new question if you still have trouble to solve it.